# Comfortable Mexican Sofa in production: should I change a site's path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I have successfully installed Comfy and now I have to create a new site. I can see the admin page, but when I try to reach the newly created site , I get error (in browser):

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

In case I have provided (on the site creation step):

```
     - Label : mysite
     - Identifier : mysite
     - Hostname: mysite.com
     - Path: (empty)
```

I can see in development, that for the `path` is stated `localhost`, how it should be for the production?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was so obvious, but a man under pressure is almost blind...

So, in a fresh deployed Comfortable Mexican sofa , first a site should be created , and second - a page in this site. If there is no page - the error message appears.

I hope this would help somebody.

Comment: Google Chrome clobbers 404 responses with its own useless page. In Firefox you can actually see a message of what went wrong. Tailing log helps too.